# Let $A \in$ Mat$_{n,n}(\mathbb R)$ be invertible and have the property that every row sum is $1$. Prove $A^{-1}$ has the same row sum property.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in$ Mat$_{n,n}(\mathbb R)$ be invertible and have the property that every row sum is $1$. Prove $A^{-1}$ has the same row sum property.

I have tried the following:

$\sum_{j=1}^n (AA^{-1})_{i,j} = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n A_{i_k}A_{k,j}^{-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n A_{i_k}A_{k,j}^{-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n A_{i_k} \sum_{j=1}^n A_{k,j}^{-1} $

However, I don't get any result.

Please help, I've tried to solve this problem for some time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that a matrix has every row sum equal to $1$ if and only if $\vec{v}=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Is there a solution not involving eigenvalues and eigenvectors, because this exercise is in a chapter before that theory.

Comment: Well, all you really need is the observation that $A\vec{v}=\vec{v}$, where $\vec{v}$ is the all $1$'s vector.

Comment: Yes I need this observation for $A^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, you need to prove $A^{-1}\vec{v}=\vec{v}$ using the fact that $A\vec{v}=\vec{v}$...or maybe it's better to write that as $\vec{v}=A\vec{v}$...

Comment: Ahh, I see $A^{-1}v = \frac 1 1 v$ so the sum is equal to 1. Thanks.